# Can I delay an alert in jquery?

Tags: jquery, delay, alert

I want an alert to come up after so many seconds rather than instantly, is there a way I can do this in jquery? So far I've tried the following but I believe delay is specifically for animations. Thanks.

```
alert ("Death").delay(1000);
```

Comment: Run a timeout perhaps?

Comment: `delay is specifically for animations` No it isn't specifically for animations but for any logic set in queue. Animations in jQuery are put by default in fx queue. In your case, to use it, it could be: `$(window).delay(1000).queue(alert.bind(window, "Death"));`. You see, you have better to forget about using jq delay here...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() { alert("Death"); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

No need for jquery for this just stick it in a plain old `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function () {
    alert();
}, 1000);
```

Docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Bear in bind if your using certain frameworks, such as angular, they have their own 'variants' to deal with databinding etc. Just a FYI.

Answer (score 1):

the easiet way is `setTimeout`, though if you are using underscore.js, you could do it like:-

```
_.delay(alert, 1000, "Death");
```

> _.delay(function, wait, *arguments)

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/38u8c8tu/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, via a callback:

```
function sample() {
    alert("This is sample function");
}

$(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        setTimeout(sample, 2000);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah apart from setting timeout. you can as well append the alert or prompt

```
setTimeout(function() {
var addmust = prompt("Please if you dont mind may we Know who you are");
$("#addname").append(addmust);
}, 6000);
```

html code

```
<p>Please rate us <span id="addname"></span>
```